# popToRootViewControllerAnimated causing a crash when ARC enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, poptoviewcontroller

I have a non-arc project. Within my project, I have enabled arc in a few ViewControllers using `-fobjc-arc`. If I call `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` from an arc enabled VC, I get a crash.. If I remove arc from that VC, then `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` works fine but this time other things stops working.. What can I do? Thanks..

Comment: In your xCode Go Edit->Refactor->Convert to arc-> You should properly check & uncheck files which you need arc or not.

Comment: Can you please post some code ? So we can get idea what is the issue

Comment: Nobody here can help with a crash unless you show the details of the crash. Where is the stack trace? What sort of crash is it? What line does it crash on?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but some suggested troubleshooting approaches:

Have you stepped through with a debugger and/or added logs statements showing the process as you pop? It could be that an object needs to be marked with the modifier:

```
__autoreleasing
```

. . typically this is implicit, but there's a few situations where it needs to be explicit.

Also try setting NSZombieEnabled on your scheme, so show which object is being messaged after it has been released - the problem is likely to be a dangling pointer.

Do you have any 'assign' or __unsafe_unretained scoped properties? A subtle change in life-cycle may be exposing a problem here.